# interfacing with ELM 327 bluetooth by writing commands to a stream

Tags: c#

First time posting. Is it possible to return a string to a separate form. Below one can find the piece of code i am dealing with.

```
public int GetValue(IBoardInterface boardInterface)
{        
    if (boardInterface is BluetoothInterface)
    {
        string PIDair = "010B\r"; // if elm is connected,return pid command
        //   return PIDair;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("Board Interface not supported");
}
```

The return string needs to be returned here:

```
byte[] PID = new byte[2];

PID[1] = Convert.ToByte(sensor.GetValue(this));// here comes the return string

byte[] byteAir = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(PID));

stream.Write(byteAir, 0, byteAir.Length);
```

Also the \r is important to use as I am waiting for a return message from a bluetooth device. Hope I am clear of my problem.

Comment: No your question is not clear at all. Is it your intention to write the byte sequence `{0x01, 0x0B}` terminated by a `\r` to your device?

Comment: The string will be sent to a ELM 327 device. As I am using stream sockets for the Bluetooth application, and once I send a string command, I except a return message containing sensor data.

Comment: I would suggest you do a web search for Project Detroit. It's a C# application that uses serial ELM 327 communications via Bluetooth. The communications class is pretty full featured and you can learn a lot from looking at the source code. It's where I learned most of what I now know about OBD2. https://obd.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already connected successfully with the ELm 327 by sending some AT commands such as AT@1 which I have also got a reply. My problem is that I need to return a string e.g.   "010B" from a separate class to a Bluetooth stream. Now if I try to use a return statement containing the written string, an error will occur showing cannot convert type 'string' to 'int' which is obvious. Now I need a method that can return a string without converting it to another format if possible.